# Firebase and Ionic 1.x - unable to add several objects at once to DB

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

The usual usage of my app `(ionic 1.x and firebase)` is pushing one object at a time, but there might be a case where several objects must be added to the DB one after another. The official docs say nothing about such case. This is the code for pushing one object each time:

```
this.addExpenseToDB = function (expense, uid) {
  var newExpenseKey = firebase.database().ref().child('expenses').push().key;
  var updates = {};
  var keyByDate = "someKey";

  updates['/user-data/' + uid + '/' + keyByDate + '/'+ newExpenseKey] = expense;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
};
```

Two questions, `A`: How can I push several objects at once? `B` How can I get a confirmation (promise? callback?) that the data saved successfully to the DB? The docs, again, are lacking this information :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fan an object, similar to what you are doing now. First you need to pass an array of objects to add to the database, then fan them out like you current do in a loop:

```
this.addExpenseToDB = function (arr) {
    // arr: [{expense: ..., uid: ...}];

    var updates = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var newExpenseKey = firebase.database().ref().child('expenses').push().key;
        var keyByDate = "someKey";
        updates['/user-data/' + arr[i].uid + '/' + keyByDate + '/'+ newExpenseKey] = arr[i].expense;
    }

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
};
```

`push(...)` returns a promise so listen for the response:

```
this.addExpenseToDB([expense: ..., uid: ...])
    .then(response => {

    })
    .catch(error => {

    });
```

With callbacks

```
this.addExpenseToDB = function (arr, callback) {
    ...
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates, function(error) {
        callback(error);
    });
}
this.updated = function(error) {
    if(error)
        // error
    else
       // success
}
this.addExpenseToDB([expense: ..., uid: ...], this.updated);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not using `es6`, do I still get to enjoy the `promise` functionality?

Comment: Yes, write a callback. Lots of questions on how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I got you right. Could you please see the updated question?

Comment: Added callback.

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new today.